# How to change yii2 pluginOptions value

Tags: javascript, jquery

From Thailand.

Below is the selected dropdownlist that I want to make a change by onchange another dropdown list

```
<select class="select1ex8-box" name="select2_ajax" pluginOptions='{"allowClear":"1","minimumInputLength":0,"ajax":{"url":"\/ezforms2\/select2\/find-component","dataType":"json","data":"function(params) { return {q:params.term, ezf_field_id:\u00271606745049066915700\u0027, ezf_id:\u00271606745049064379400\u0027}; }"},"escapeMarkup":"function (markup) { return markup; }","templateResult":"function(result) { return result.text; }","templateSelection":"function (selection) { return selection.text; }"}' ezf_field_id="1606745049066915700" modal_size="modal-xxl" template_items="" ezf_id="1550037618000870100"></select>
```

I try to change this selected drop downlist using this function but there is no anything change

```
$('.select2ex8-box select').on('change',function(e){
    var select2ex8 = parseInt($('.select2ex8-box option:selected').val());
     $('.select1ex8-box select').val(select2ex8).change();
});
```

Comment: This is all client side scripting, yes?  Create a runnable script to the best of your ability.  Hit the snippet button and away you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer dependent-dropdown jQuery plugin by Krajee.
Click [here](https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop)! for more